# Onde fechar EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Java, e estou com dúvida aonde fechar o Entity Manager.

Tenho uma classe Abstrata `AbstractService<T>` que é extendida por todas as entidades do sistema, e essa classe possui os métodos de persistência.

Em uma servlet qualquer, eu instancio uma ou mais classes de serviços (cada classe de entidade possui uma classe de serviço, como por exemplo a classe `Category_DTO` e sua classe de serviço `CategoryServiceImpl`), que contém queries de busca, e ao mesmo tempo estende `AbstractService<T>`

Minha dúvida é o melhor lugar para fechar o entityManager, `em.close()`.

Pensei em fechar na própria servlet, no final da mesma, utilizando a instância de `DocumentServiceImpl` com `dsi.closeTX()`, mas achei meio gambiarrado (lembrando que uma servlet pode conter várias classes de serviço, e eu teria que fechar o entitymanager de cada uma que estendeu `AbstractService` e criou o entitymanager).

Vou mandar um JSP, com um código de exemplo que é utilizado em servlets, onde retornarei todas as categorias. No final do JSP estou fechando o entitymanager, mas acredito que o correto seria fechar na classe de persistência e não na servlet.

Segue o código:

Entidade:

```
    package freedom.technology.domain.document;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import freedom.technology.enus.CategoryType;

@Entity
@Table(name = "FRE_CL_GED_CATEGORY")
@NamedQueries({    
    @NamedQuery(name="Category_DTO.findAllCategories", query="SELECT a FROM Category_DTO a WHERE :search is null OR (a.id LIKE :search OR a.description LIKE :search) ORDER BY a.description ASC"),
    @NamedQuery(name="Category_DTO.findAllCategoriesDESC", query="SELECT a FROM Category_DTO a WHERE :search is null OR (a.id LIKE :search OR a.description LIKE :search) ORDER BY a.description DESC"),
    @NamedQuery(name="Category_DTO.findAllCategoriesByType", query="SELECT a FROM Category_DTO a WHERE (:search is null OR (a.id LIKE :search OR a.description LIKE :search)) AND a.type = :type ORDER BY a.description ASC"),
    @NamedQuery(name="Category_DTO.findAllCategoriesByTypeDESC", query="SELECT a FROM Category_DTO a WHERE (:search is null OR (a.id LIKE :search OR a.description LIKE :search)) AND a.type = :type ORDER BY a.description DESC"),
    @NamedQuery(name="Category_DTO.getNumberOfCategories", query="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Category_DTO"),
    @NamedQuery(name="Category_DTO.getNumberOfCategoriesBySearchCondition", query="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Category_DTO a WHERE :search is null OR (a.id LIKE :search OR a.description LIKE :search) ORDER BY a.id DESC"),
}) 


public class Category_DTO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)   
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="type")
    private CategoryType type;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public CategoryType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setType(CategoryType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Classe que retorna registros com base em uma pesquisa específica:

```
package freedom.technology.service.document.impl;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import freedom.technology.domain.document.Category_DTO;
import freedom.technology.domain.document.Subject_DTO;
import freedom.technology.enus.CategoryType;
import freedom.technology.exception.ExceptionType;
import freedom.technology.exception.FREBDCoreException;
import freedom.technology.service.AbstractService;
import freedom.technology.service.document.api.CategoryService;

public class CategoryServiceImpl extends AbstractService<Category_DTO> implements CategoryService {

    @Override
    protected Class<Category_DTO> getEntityClass() {
        return Category_DTO.class;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Category_DTO> findAllCategories(Integer pageSize, Integer pageNumber, String searchCondition, String orderBy)
            throws FREBDCoreException {

        List<Category_DTO> result = null;

        if (pageSize == null || pageNumber == null){
            throw new FREBDCoreException(ExceptionType.NULLPOINTER, "Parametro null: pageSize/pageNumber"); 
        }       
        try {
            TypedQuery<Category_DTO> query = em.createNamedQuery("Category_DTO.findAllCategories", Category_DTO.class);
            if(orderBy.equals("DESC")){
                query = em.createNamedQuery("Category_DTO.findAllCategoriesDESC", Category_DTO.class);
            }

            if(searchCondition != null) {           
                query.setParameter("search", "%"+searchCondition+"%");
            } else {
                query.setParameter("search", null);             
            }

            query.setFirstResult(pageSize*pageNumber);
            query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
            result =  query.getResultList();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new FREBDCoreException(ExceptionType.NORESULT, "findAllCategories");
        }
        return result;  
    }

    @Override
    public List<Category_DTO> findAllCategoriesByType(Integer pageSize, Integer pageNumber, CategoryType type, String searchCondition, String orderBy)
            throws FREBDCoreException {

        List<Category_DTO> result = null;

        if (pageSize == null || pageNumber == null){
            throw new FREBDCoreException(ExceptionType.NULLPOINTER, "Parametro null: pageSize/pageNumber"); 
        }       
        try {
            TypedQuery<Category_DTO> query = em.createNamedQuery("Category_DTO.findAllCategoriesByType", Category_DTO.class);
            if(orderBy.equals("DESC")){
                query = em.createNamedQuery("Category_DTO.findAllCategoriesByTypeDESC", Category_DTO.class);
            }

            if(searchCondition != null) {           
                query.setParameter("search", "%"+searchCondition+"%");
            } else {
                query.setParameter("search", null);             
            }

            if(type != null) {          
                query.setParameter("type", type);
            } else {
                query.setParameter("type", null);               
            }

            query.setFirstResult(pageSize*pageNumber);
            query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
            result =  query.getResultList();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new FREBDCoreException(ExceptionType.NORESULT, "findAllCategoriesByType");
        }
        return result;  
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumberOfCategories() throws FREBDCoreException {
        int result;

        try {           
            TypedQuery<Long> query = em.createNamedQuery("Category_DTO.getNumberOfCategories", Long.class);
            result = query.getSingleResult().intValue();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            result = 0;
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumberOfCategories(String searchCondition)
            throws FREBDCoreException {

        int result;

        try {           
            TypedQuery<Long> query = em.createNamedQuery("Category_DTO.getNumberOfCategoriesBySearchCondition", Long.class);

            if(searchCondition != null) {           
                query.setParameter("search", "%"+searchCondition+"%");
            } else {
                query.setParameter("search", null);             
            }

            result = query.getSingleResult().intValue();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            result = 0;
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Classe de persistência:

```
package freedom.technology.service;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import freedom.technology.exception.ExceptionType;
import freedom.technology.exception.FREBDCoreException;
import freedom.technology.utils.PersisteUtils;

public abstract class AbstractService<T> implements GenericService<T> {

    private static EntityManagerFactory factory = PersisteUtils.getEntityManagerFactory();
    protected EntityManager em;
    protected abstract Class<T> getEntityClass();

    public AbstractService() {
        em = factory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void beginTX(){
        em.getTransaction().begin();
    }

    public void commitTX(){
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public void closeTX(){
        em.close();     
    }

    public void rollback(){
        em.getTransaction().rollback();     
    }

    public T findById(Integer id){
        T result = null;

        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin(); 
            result = em.find(this.getEntityClass(), id);
            em.getTransaction().commit(); 
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void persist(T entity) {
        try { 
            em.getTransaction().begin(); 
            em.persist(entity); 
            em.getTransaction().commit(); 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(); 
            em.getTransaction().rollback(); 
        } 
    } 

    public void merge(T entity) {
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin(); 
            em.merge(entity); 
            em.getTransaction().commit(); 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(); 
            em.getTransaction().rollback(); 
        } 
    }  

    public void removeObject(T entity) {
        try { 
            em.getTransaction().begin(); 
            em.remove(entity); 
            em.getTransaction().commit(); 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(); 
            em.getTransaction().rollback(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Jsp exemplo, fechando o entityManager no final:

```
<%@page import="freedom.technology.domain.document.Category_DTO"%>
<%@page import="freedom.technology.service.document.api.CategoryService"%>
<%@page import="freedom.technology.service.document.impl.CategoryServiceImpl"%>

<%@page import="java.util.List"%>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<%

    CategoryService ds = new CategoryServiceImpl();
    List<Category_DTO> listCategory = ds.findAllCategories(100, 0, null, null);

    for(Category_DTO category : listCategory){

        out.print("Categorias:");
        out.print("<br><br>");
        out.print("Categoria: " + category);
        out.print("<br>");
    }

    ds.closeTX();
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dica relacionada, sugiro repensar essa classe `AbstractService`, da forma que esta essa hierarquia vai crescer e se expandir por todo o seu sistema, num futuro proximo isso sera um verdadeiro pesadelo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Separação de responsabilidades

A maioria dos sistemas pode ser dividida em algumas camadas conceituais:

- **Interface** ou **apresentação:** telas/formulários/páginas ou fachada de serviço para consumo externo.
- **Aplicação:** recebe requisições do usuário ou dos sistemas externos e invoca os componentes de negócio para processar as requisições.
- **Negócio:** processamento das requisições.
- **Persistência:** a base de dados onde tudo é persistido.

Se você conseguir manter cada código no seu lugar, fica mais fácil perceber onde abrir e fechar conexão com o banco de dados (ou "sessão", ou "contexto"... dependendo da cultura/plataforma/framework) e onde abrir e fechar a transação.

## Gerência de sessão e transação de banco de dados

Uma transação de banco de dados serve para garantir a atomicidade de uma operação. Ou seja, se a operação vai alterar dois registros: ou ambos serão alterados com sucesso ou nenhum será alterado - se der erro na alteração do segundo, desfaz-se a alteração do primeiro.

Pensando em **atomicidade de operação**, não faz sentido o gerenciamento da transação estar dentro da classe responsável pela persistência de uma única entidde!

Então uma operação (ou "processo de negócio") sabe se ela exige uma transação ou não: se ela vai alterar mais de um registro, ela vai querer atomicidade, então vai exigir transação.

```
public void processo_de_negocio() {
    
    // Não ligo sobre transação. Uma transação com commit implícito já serve pra mim.
    // Neste caso aqui, se a transação estiver 
    // na classe de persistência deste único registro, 
    // parece ok.
    salvarRegistro(); 
}

public void processo_de_negocio2() {
    
    // Quero garantir que o salvamento dos dois registros seja atômico!
    // Então a transação não pode ser controlada pela classe 
    // de persistência de cada um dos registros.
    beginTransaction(); 
    
    salvarRegistro(); 
    salvarOutroRegistro();
    
    commitTransaction();
}
```

Muito bem. Mas o processo de negócio 2 não sabe se ele fará parte de um outro processo maior e se precisará participar da mesma transação. Então ele também não deveria cuidar da transação.

Então quem deveria cuidar da transação? **A camada de aplicativo deveria cuidar da transação**:

```
public void post() {

    beginTransaction();
    
    processo_de_negocio();
    processo_de_negocio2();
    
    commitTransaction();
}
```

E a conexão/sessão/entitymanager? **A gestão da conexão também é responsabilidade da camada de aplicativo**:

```
public void post() {

    em = factory.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    
    processo_de_negocio(em);
    processo_de_negocio2(em);
    
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
}
```

É claro que os frameworks facilitam a vida e eventualmente não precisamos ficar passando conexão/sessão/entitymanager por parâmetro, e usando estes frameworks também não precisamos gerir a transação na mão.

Mas conceitualmente a idéia é esta e é assim que os frameworks trabalham.

## O seu código

Isto posto, vamos dar uma olhada no seu código.

### A classe *AbstractService*

Ora, se a gestão da transação é função da camada de aplicativo, **quase todo o trabalho realizado hoje por sua classe *AbstractService* está no lugar errado**.

Se você passar a gestão da transação para o lugar certo, a maioria dos métodos que estão hoje em *AbstractService* deixam de ser necessários e os métodos que sobrarem você pode passar para a *CategoryServiceImpl*, pois eles terão uma única linha cada (exemplos: `em.persist(entity);`, `return em.find(this.getEntityClass(), id);`).

E já que você nunca vai precisar representar a *CategoryServiceImpl* na forma de *AbstractService*, e nem há muito código a reaproveitar, esta herança é completamente desnecessária.

### A página JSP

O código aí também não está respeitando a definição de camadas, pois ele mistura apresentação e lógica de aplicativo.

Se você quiser mais facilidade de manutenção e de reutilização, você pode criar uma classe *Servlet* cujo método *doGet* entregaria esta lista de entidades para a página JSP. E, no caso de ser necessário um processamento de negócio no submit da página, o método *doPost* trataria de obter a sessão e gerenciar a transação, como no exemplo que mostrei acima.

### O tratamento de exceções

Você está sumindo com os possíveis erros. Quando eles acontecerem, o seu aplicativo vai se comportar de uma maneira quase imprevisível e de difícil diagnóstico.

Não adianta imprimir a exceção no log, o usuário precisa saber que a operação dele não ocorreu com sucesso.

Também não adianta, no *catch*, retornar zero ao tentar ler "quantos registros". Ali só vai dar erro se houver algo muito errado, como por exemplo o nome da tabela ter mudado; encobrir este erro retornando um confuso Zero não vai ajudar no diagnóstico do problema.

Algumas vezes faz sentido um tratamento de exceção nas camadas inferiores mas, **de maneira geral, o tratamento de exceções também pertence à camada de aplicativo**.

Então você deveria retirar a maior parte do tratamento de exceções que tem hoje, e mover para a camada de aplicativo.

O servlet (pertencente à camada de aplicativo), ficaria afinal mais ou menos assim:

```
public void post() {
    try {
        em = factory.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        
        processo_de_negocio(em);
        processo_de_negocio2(em);
        
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // aqui, avisa o usuário de maneira amigável, 
        // e mostra ou registra a exceção no log
    }
}
```

Um *finally* também seria útil ali para garantir o rollback e fechamento da conexão (ou sua devolução para o pool) imediatamente.

Nota final: depois de entender estes conceitos, considere usar frameworks para reduzir o tanto de código que você precisa escrever e preocupações que você precisa ter.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde,

Obrigado pela resposta.

Com base em estudos que realizei e visando atender as necessidades do software, encontrei a seguinte solução:

Realizei o gerenciamento das instâncias do EntityManager e transactions através de uma classe filtro da javax.servlet, que filtrará as requisições, instanciará o entityManager e abrirá transaction caso necessário: (SecurityFilter implements Filter).
 -Antes de iniciar a servlet eu crio a instância do em e abro a transação;
 -Após finalizar a servlet, o filtro commita a transação, e finaliza o entityManager;
 -Em caso de erro, rollback em tudo, garantindo a atomicidade.

```
package freedom.technology.session;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import freedom.technology.service.PersistEngine;


@WebFilter("/*")
public class SecurityFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession();
        UserSession userSession = (UserSession) (session.getAttribute("UserSession"));

        String url = httpRequest.getRequestURI();
        StringBuilder urlToRedirect = new StringBuilder("?");

        if ((userSession == null) && (url.startsWith("/FRE_BPM/page-wrapper"))) {

            //redirecionamento de url
            //documentos e tarefas enviadas por email, etc
            HashMap<String, String[]> params = (HashMap<String, String[]>) request.getParameterMap();
            Set<Entry<String, String[]>> setParams = params.entrySet();

            for (Iterator<Entry<String, String[]>> it = setParams.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                 Entry<String, String[]> entry = it.next();

                 urlToRedirect.append(entry.getKey()).append("=").append(request.getParameter(entry.getKey())).append("&");
            }

            httpResponse.sendRedirect("/FRE_BPM/login.jsp".concat(urlToRedirect.toString()));
        } else {            

            boolean transactional = true;

            if(url.contains(".") && !url.endsWith(".jsp")){
                transactional = false;
            }

            if(transactional){

                System.out.println("Iniciando transação para a url: " + url);
                try {
                    PersistEngine.beginTransaction();
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                    PersistEngine.commit();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    if ( PersistEngine.getEntityManager() != null && PersistEngine.getEntityManager().isOpen()) {
                        PersistEngine.rollback();
                    }

                } finally {
                    PersistEngine.closeEntityManager();
                }
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }

}
```

Migrei todo a lógica de persistência para uma classe que criei (PersitEngine). Esta classe criará as instâncias do entityManager, controlará as transações, e realizará as ações de persist, merge e remove.

```
package freedom.technology.service;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

import freedom.technology.utils.PersisteUtils;

public class PersistEngine {

    private static EntityManagerFactory factory = PersisteUtils.getEntityManagerFactory();
    private static final ThreadLocal<EntityManager> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<EntityManager>();

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        EntityManager em = threadLocal.get();

        if (em == null) {
            em = factory.createEntityManager();
            threadLocal.set(em);
        }
        return em;
    }

    public static void closeEntityManager() {
        EntityManager em = threadLocal.get();
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
            threadLocal.set(null);
        }
    }

    public static void closeEntityManagerFactory() {
        factory.close();
    }

    public static void beginTransaction() {
        getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
    }

    public static void rollback() {
        getEntityManager().getTransaction().rollback();
    }

    public static void commit() {
        getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public static <T> void persist(T entity){

        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public static <T> void remove(T entity){        

        getEntityManager().remove(entity);      
    }

    public static <T> T merge(T entity){

        return getEntityManager().merge(entity);        
    }

    public static <T> Object findById(Class<T> clazz, Integer id){

        T result = getEntityManager().find(clazz, id);

        return result;
    }
}
```

As classes AbstractService e GenericService serão excluídas, pois não necessitarei mais das mesmas.

Comment: Bacana, você está caminhando para a idéia da minha resposta: gerenciar sessão/conexão e transação de banco de dados na camada de aplicativo. Nunca fiz isso em um Filter; fiquei meio receoso mas não consegui pensar agora no que poderia dar errado...

Comment: Dica: não adianta muito começar sua reposta dizendo "obrigado pela resposta", uma vez que se aparecerem outras, não se saberá do que vc está falando. E agradecimentos de maneira geral são meio dispensáveis por aqui :-) Uma opção melhor é votar nas respostas que lhe forem úteis.